# C# Geometry get points (open line)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an incredibly simple `Geometry` object:

```
var geometry = Geometry.Parse("F1M-76,-26.5L14,-26.5 14,-17.5 156,-17.5");
```

I want to get the points inside that `Geometry` object:

```
-76,-26.5
14,-26.5
14,-17.5
156,-17.5
```

What's the best way to get these points?

I tried:

```
var allfigs = geometry.GetFlattenedPathGeometry().Figures.ToList();
allfigs.AddRange(geometry.GetOutlinedPathGeometry().Figures);
allfigs.AddRange(geometry.GetWidenedPathGeometry(new Pen()).Figures);
```

The only line that gives me figures is the last line, however the points in these figures don't match the original points... They are offset by the width of the `Pen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
var geometry = Geometry.Parse("F1M-76,-26.5L14,-26.5 14,-17.5 156,-17.5");

char[] UpperCaseChars = new char[]
{
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H',
    'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
    'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X',
    'Y', 'Z',' '
};

int indexOfM = geometry.ToString().IndexOf('M');
var a = geometry.ToString().Substring(indexOfM).Split(UpperCaseChars);
```

Comment: It works, but it's a bit hacky. Can't guarantee it'll keep working as my lines get more detailed.

Comment: Actually I am using this code for almost a year without any problem as I didn't found any alternative.

Comment: Your code is working fine, and it inspired me to try something else which worked. I'll mark your code as the answer. It inspired me to `ToString` and `Parse` my geometry object and it seems to give `LineSegment`s after I did that :) PS: Make sure to have `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in there somewhere!